# AWS S3 getSignedUrl loop not working properly?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I want to send back two S3 pre-signed URL's for each key in [user.idKey, user.selfieKey] array in my Express route.

I know that S3 is successfully getting the pre-signed URLS because they will log to the console with the callback *console.log(url)*.

I also tried using "await" in front of the getSignedUrl method but I don't think that works for S3..???

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
router.get(`/api/verification/load`, auth, async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ GETS A USER })

    let urlArray = []

    const keyArray = [user.idKey, user.selfieKey]
   
    for (const key in keyArray) {
      s3VerificationBucket.getSignedUrl(
        "getObject",
        {
          Bucket: "app-verification",
          Key: key,
          Expires: 30,
        },
        (err, url) => urlArray.push(url) // when console.log(url) it logs urls 
      )
    }

    if (urlArray.length === 0) {  
      console.log("URL ARRAY EMPTY")  -> RETURNS "URL ARRAY EMPTY"
    }

    const idUrl = urlArray[0]
    const selfieUrl = urlArray[1]

    res.send({ user, idUrl, selfieUrl })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending your response synchronously. You are signing your links asynchronously. So the array is populated AFTER you have already responded.

Instead, use `s3VerificationBucket.getSignedUrl(...).promise()` to get a promise for each operation.

Use `Promise.all(...)` to wait on the result of all operations before responding.

Only after you have processed all async work should you `res.send(...)`.

Comment: Thank you @Chase but how would I apply that to my existing code?